# Why do we need to explicitly declare pointer types in c++?

Tags: c++, memory

I am taking a really interesting CE course in conjunction with a C++ course. In CE, I have gotten more in-depth understanding of how memory works. So, why do we need to explicitly declare pointer types in c++? A pointer is simply a memory cell (or cells) that hold an address to a data type; while data types will obviously require different memory allocation, why should a pointer? AKA, why can't pointer types be generalized in C++ if all of them hold equal things, memory addresses?

Comment: Did reading any of [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+pointer) not help?

Comment: Kinda violates the concept of a strictly-typed language. The whole point of the type is to define how the bytes at the address are interpreted, because interpretation is the only thing that matters when it comes to bytes stored in memory.

Comment: So, why do we need to explicitly declare data types in c++? A data-type is simply a memory cell (or cells) that hold bits. AKA (also known as), why can't data types be generalized in C++ if all of them hold equal things, bits?

Comment: Not all data types require different memory allocation. Type is not about size, it is about how you are allowed to use it and giving the compiler the information it needs to enforce rules. You should not be allowed to write an integer through a string pointer, for example. Enforcing type rules makes programming safer and more reliable.

Comment: You should provide some example code where you need to *"explicitly declare pointer types"* and explain how would it look like otherwise.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Except, C++ is not strictly-typed. It is statically-typed.

Answer (score 7):

Because one of the main reasons to use C++ is **type safety**.

If the language didn't know the difference between an `int*` and a `MyClass*`, then you could accidentally assign an `int*` to a `MyClass*`, and the runtime behaviour of your program would be undefined. The goal in C++ is for the compiler to detect such bugs, and that wouldn't be possible without different pointer types.

```
struct MyClass
{
    double d;
};

void f(MyClass* ptr)
{
    ptr->d = 1.0;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    f(&i); // error detected at compile time
}
```

Comment: Haha, thanks for keeping it concise! So, it's not due to the fact that it "could not" be done, rather that it is more convenient (allows for type safety) by doing so?

Comment: @MichaelW: There are other technical reasons. Without different pointer types, it wouldn't really be C++ anymore. Let me see if I can come up with a good example...

Comment: @MichaelW: I see there's already a good example in iBug's answer, so I'll just leave mine as it is.

Answer (score 2):

There's something called "strict aliasing rule" in C++, which is more or less the same as "type safety".

In the following code:

```
int a = 123456;
void foo(float *p){
    *p = 1.0f;
    std::cout << a;
}
```

The compiler is allowed to assume that `p` never points to `a` and make optimization. If it's `void *p` then the assumption would fire.

Comment: *which is more or less the same as "type safety"* - Well, I'd say it's more "less" than "more" :) After all, pointers to identical types `struct S { int i; }` and `struct T { int i; }` still aren't assignable to each other.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to assembly language programming, you are going to find there are no pointer types.

You could do what you are asking using (void*) all the time but that undermines the usefulness of the language.

if you have

```
class CLASS
{
...
public:
     void doSomething () 
...
} ;

....
void *x = new CLASS ;
```

Then you are not going to be able to do

```
x->doSomething () ;
```

because the compiler is not going to know what the attributes of "x" are because C++ uses compile-time binding to functions.

There are languages with run-time binding that will allow you do that.